# Chrome extension. This extension may have been corrupted

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I faced strange bug with my extension for chrome.
If extension was loaded from source (load unpacked), it works good.
But if it was added from webstore, an error occurs.
Extension is simple play/pause button for website with podcasts.

How to reproduce:

- install the [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/playpause-button-for-pock/ogdnlmiknnmedpcnjnkjncdjjgfdkiik);
- click on the extension button for open pocket casts site;
- sign in to the site ("start trial" button. Registration is required);
- find any podcast and play it;
- twice click on the extension button.

After that the button disappears and extension in extensions list (chrome://extensions/) contains text "This extension may have been corrupted". After click to "repair" button the extension repairs, but after second click it disappears again.

No error messages or logs, just crush. I have no idea, how to detect a bug. Webstore support can`t help.

This bug occurs only in chrome and chromium browsers, but works good in other chromium-based browsers (for example Vivaldi and Yandex).

[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VGWIPGEXs0E) for demonstration.

[Source code](https://github.com/illuzor/Play-Button-For-Pocket-Casts/tree/version2) of the extension.

I suspect line 5 or/and 7 in [log-listener.js](https://github.com/illuzor/Play-Button-For-Pocket-Casts/blob/version2/source/log-listener.js).

If found similar problems which were resolved by adding update_url to manifest, but it`s not working for me.

Comment: The error cannot be caused by the extension's code so it's either a bug in Chrome (there was one half a year ago) or you have a third-party app that modifies the extension directory in the browser profile, like an antivirus.

Comment: Looks like a chrome bug. Still occurs after antivirus disabling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with icons names. Files was "play.png/pause.png" and "Play.png/Pause.png".
Case is important.

Comment: How did you debug the issue?

Comment: I don`t remember